# A timeout occurs while reading data from Python to HID

Tags: python, linux, usb, hid, nvidia-jetson-nano

## development environment

> OS : Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.201-tegra aarch64)
>
> Language : Python 3.6
>
> Device: Jetson nano, Maxim MAX35104 EV Kit

## Issue

- A timeout occurs while reading HID data. In Python, the first device information is brought, but there is a problem that the data is not received.

## Code

```py
import usb.core

vendor_id = 0x04fa
product_id = 0x3900

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=vendor_id, idProduct=product_id)

if device is None:
    raise ValueError("Not Found USB")

for cfg in device:
    print(f"Configuration: {cfg}")
    for intf in cfg:
        print(f"Interface: {intf}")
        for ep in intf:
            print(f"Endpoint: {ep}")

device.set_configuration()

def read_data():
    endpoint_address = 0x81
    size = 64
    timeout = 1000

    data = device.read(endpoint_address, size, timeout)

data = read_data()

print(data)
```

## what i checked

- The corresponding device is confirmed in dmesg, and the information of the corresponding device can be read in the Python code.

1. dmesg
   [image]
2. python Program
   [image]
3. Reconnect the USB device
4. Restart the USB device
5. Run the program with sudo
6. Change Timeout to 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

## Changes from previous issue

- By modifying the code, Timeout does not appear.
  However, all the data comes in as 0.
- The endpoint out is set to 0x1 and the length is set to 64 bytes.
- Data is received, but there is no change in the data for the sensor.

## Device information

```bash
DEVICE ID 04fa:3900 on Bus 001 Address 008 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :    0x8 (8 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x04fa
 idProduct              : 0x3900
 bcdDevice              :    0x2 Device 0.02
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Maxim Integrated
 iProduct               :    0x2 DS3900 Module HIDClass
 iSerialNumber          :    0x0
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x29 (41 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
INTERFACE 0: Human Interface Device ====================                                       [15/521]
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x3 Human Interface Device
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
      ENDPOINT 0x1: Interrupt OUT ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x1 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
```

## Modified code

```py
import usb.core
import usb.util

vendor_id = 0x04fa
product_id = 0x3900

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=vendor_id, idProduct=product_id)

if device is None:
    raise ValueError("Not Found USB")

interface = 0
endpoint_in = 0x81
endpoint_out = 0x1

device.set_configuration()

try:
    while True:
        try:
            data = device.read(endpoint_out, 64, timeout=1000)
            print("Received data:", data)
            print("bytes data:" , bytes(data))
        except usb.core.USBError as e:
            if e.errno == 110:  # (110: Operation timed out)
                print("Time Out")
                continue
            else:
                raise
finally:
    usb.util.dispose_resources(device)
```

## Data output

```bash
bytes data: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Received data: array('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
bytes data: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Received data: array('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
bytes data: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```